# Unable to insert into remote server using linked server

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query and works when the source and destination tables are on the same server however doesnt work when they are on different servers. However if I only run the select, it pulls records but doesnt insert.

```
INSERT INTO [GBIPS-I-DB324D].[CoreReferenceStaging].[dbo].[tempCompany] 

    select
        fp.companyId,fp.fiscalYear,fp.fiscalQuarter,fi.financialperiodid, fi.periodEndDate,
        fc.currencyId,fp.periodtypeid,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fp.companyId, 
        fp.fiscalYear, fp.fiscalQuarter ORDER BY fi.periodEndDate DESC) rowno   

    from 
        ciqFinPeriod fp
        inner join ciqcompany c on c.companyId = 36623 
        --fp.companyId

        join ciqFinInstance fi on fi.financialperiodid = fp.financialperiodid
        join ciqFinInstanceToCollection ic on ic.financialInstanceId = fi.financialInstanceId
        left  join ciqFinCollection fc on fc.financialCollectionId = ic.financialCollectionId
        left join ciqFinCollectionData fd on fd.financialCollectionId = fc.financialCollectionId
    where 
        fp.periodTypeId = @periodtypeId
        and fi.periodenddate >= @date
        and fi.financialInstanceId > @maxFinancialInstanceId
```

If i query the select , I do get the results but it doesnt seem to insert and neither a error is thrown.

I tried the following as well but prefixing the source server names but it didnt make a difference

```
 INSERT INTO [GBIPS-I-DB324D].[CoreReferenceStaging].[dbo].[tempCompany] 
select top 10
        fp.companyId,fp.fiscalYear,fp.fiscalQuarter,fi.financialperiodid, fi.periodEndDate,
        fc.currencyId,fp.periodtypeid,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fp.companyId, 
        fp.fiscalYear, fp.fiscalQuarter ORDER BY fi.periodEndDate DESC) rowno   

    from 
        [GBIPS-I-DB48D\SQL2008R2].[xpressfeed_dev].[dbo].ciqFinPeriod fp
        inner join [GBIPS-I-DB48D\SQL2008R2].[xpressfeed_dev].[dbo].ciqcompany c on c.companyId = 36623 
        --fp.companyId

        join [GBIPS-I-DB48D\SQL2008R2].[xpressfeed_dev].[dbo].ciqFinInstance fi on fi.financialperiodid = fp.financialperiodid
        join [GBIPS-I-DB48D\SQL2008R2].[xpressfeed_dev].[dbo].ciqFinInstanceToCollection ic on ic.financialInstanceId = fi.financialInstanceId
        left  join [GBIPS-I-DB48D\SQL2008R2].[xpressfeed_dev].[dbo].ciqFinCollection fc on fc.financialCollectionId = ic.financialCollectionId
        left join [GBIPS-I-DB48D\SQL2008R2].[xpressfeed_dev].[dbo].ciqFinCollectionData fd on fd.financialCollectionId = fc.financialCollectionId
    where 
        fp.periodTypeId = @periodtypeId
        --and fi.financialInstanceId > @maxFinancialInstanceId
```

Comment: Do you have any error? Do you have the permissions to insert on linked server?

Comment: No error . What permissions are required ?

Comment: When someone have no permission to insert it get the error "The insert permission was denied...". To insert in any table you need the INSERT permission on that table. So how did you check that there was no insert done?

Comment: I did select top 10 on the destination table and the query kept on running without a result. When I did edit result set from Ssms , I got timeout error. What I hAve noticed is that if I explicitly hard code values and send across one row then it inserts

Comment: So how is it an insert permission issue

Comment: >>>if I explicitly hard code values and send across one row then it inserts<<< If you had no INSERT permission, you'd not be able to insert even one value, so it's not permission issue. Do you have an access to remote server, can you query sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks?

Comment: I don't have access to the remote server. May have to request Db team. What will that query tell ?

Comment: You'll be able to clearly see what it's waiting for. Try to exec it on your server, maybe the problem is on YOUR server

Comment: But...how many rows are you trying to insert? Did you try not to hardcode the values but simply insert top 10 rows? It seems that your query simply running to slow, you just did not wait enough...

Comment: I used openquery , For one my other queries which is similar which worked. I moved the storedproc to the destination server and used open query. Not sure why that worked ?

Comment: They both worked. The difference is that when you get the records by PULLING them from linked server, you have better performance if it's operating with row sets. When you are PUSHING your rows to linked server, this is made using cursor, 1 row at a time